# The file format and extension of don't match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, asp.net-mvc, openxml

I'm creating an Excel file with multiple sheets using `DocumentFormat.OpenXml` library from my `C#` code. The file gets created without any issue and it has all the required data but when I open it, I get this error pop-up:

[image]

I have noticed that this erroneous file has a type of `XSLX file`. If it is of the type `Microsoft Excel Worksheet`, strangely, it doesn't throw any error:
[image]

I'm just not getting what is wrong here an how I can fix it. Need suggestions, please.
Below is my code snippet:

```
private static void WriteToExcelFile(HashSet<string> modules, Dictionary<string, HashSet<MyData>> dataDictionary)
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "Content\\MyDocument")))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "Content\\MyDocument"));

            string fileFullname = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "Content\\MyDocument", "MyExcel.xslx");
            SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(fileFullname, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);

            WorkbookPart workbookpart = spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart(); // Add a WorkbookPart to the document
            workbookpart.Workbook = new Workbook();

            // Add Sheets to the Workbook  
            Sheets sheets = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());

           // populate sheets
           .....

           spreadsheetDocument.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from a wrong extension: it MUST be
.xlsx
And not
.xslx